# Pig: remove tuples in inner bag

Tags: apache-pig

This is what the data looks like:

```
A: {id: int, data: {ARRAY_ELEM:(score:float, flag:boolean)}}
12, {(1.35, True), (2.46, False)}
13, {(0.98, False)}
14, {(0.23, True), (0.95, True)}
```

I want to remove all the tuples that is flagged False, without flatten the data. 
Expected output:

```
12, {(1.35, True)}
13, {}
14, {(0.23, True), (0.95, True)}
```

Is there a way I can do that in Pig Latin? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nested foreach.

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (id: int, data:bag{(score:float, flag:boolean)});
B = FOREACH A {
    filtered_data = FILTER data by flag == true;
    GENERATE id, filtered_data;
}
store B into '$output';
```

Note that your input file should not have any spaces for boolean values. 
(Meaning "{(1.35,[space]True), (2.46,[space]False)} " should be "{(1.35,True), (2.46,False)}" with no spaces after the comma.  Otherwise, you'll need to load them as chararray.

Comment: @ShuangJin, can you accept my answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Sure, Koji! Done :)